# Android : Altering the font size based on device

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to build a textview that should automatically take care of the screen size and adjust the font size accordingly so as to fill the same % of screen in all the devices. Hence I used the dp. Also I have tried sp. But I could not make it. kindly help.

Thanks in Advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"  > 

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvValue4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="I planned to use different font size for the textview on different device size so as to make the letters legible. I have already decided not to use different layouts for different devices and built a common layout to fit in all the devices. Now the only problem is on the text size."
                    android:textColor="#000000"  
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layout for different screen size as follow

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: to change the font-size better to go for various values than layouts